# Mixing OpenGL 2.0 with Modern OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-4, opengl-2.0

Is it possible to use both old and new OpenGL in one program?
Assuming I've understood the difference.

In my program I've used:

```
WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
```

But for example, can I use a function that contains this to draw a grid: **(old)**

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(-50, 0, (GLfloat)x);
    glVertex3f( 50, 0, (GLfloat)x);
    glVertex3f((GLfloat)x, 0, -50);
    glVertex3f((GLfloat)x, 0,  50);
glEnd();
```

And a function like this, to texture and render something: **(new)**

```
glUseProgram(myShader->handle());
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBindVertexArray(m_vaoID[0]);          //select first VAO
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);       //draw two triangles
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glUseProgram(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Or does the use of newer versions that make use of `vao`/`vbo`'s make functions that contain `glBegin`/`glEnd` obsolete?

I hope that makes sense. Please excuse the naivety.

Comment: Which platform are you targeting? OS X only gives you access to OpenGL 3.2, 3.3 and 4.1 functionality if you surrender compatibility profile. That is to say, you must have a core profile context for these versions on this platform. Effectively, OS X prevents you from mixing and matching (you either get 2.1 for legacy stuff or 3.2+ core), but a lot of other platforms let you use 3.2+ compatibility. Just some food for thought, if you ever think about porting to OS X -- lots of things on OS X are ***"different"*** ;)

Answer (score 4):

If it's an OpenGL 3.2 or higher [compatibility profile](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts) then yes, you can mix immediate mode calls with proper rendering.  Whether you should or not is another matter (you probably shouldn't in production code, but it can be useful for debugging).  With a core profile, you won't be able to use the deprecated APIs.

Note that prior to 3.2, there was no concept of profiles, so with a 3.0/3.1 context, things are more complicated (see link above), but in practice there isn't much use in targeting 3.0/3.1 since just about any 3.0 capable hardware will be fine with 3.2.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Thanks for posting, I'll check the link out now.